# Replace multiple words in a string variable

Tags: google-apps-script, replace

I have a Google Sheet that takes data and puts it in a calendar. This part is working well except for the name, which is taken from the title of the worksheet:

example name: "Afwezigheids Formulier Davy L. 1168555 (Antwoorden)"

I only want "Davy L. 1168555" out of this whole title, but so far I only manage to remove/replace "Afwezigheids Formulier" from the title.

My question: *is there a way to replace multiple words in different places with nothing?* I have no code experience except for copy/paste and trying to understand what is written; I have tried multiple things, but nothing worked so far.

(Yes, I could change the title, but those are automatically generated by forms, and I have a lot of forms that I would have to change then manually.)

My current code, which manages to strip out the first part of the generated worksheet name:

```
function makeCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("blabla callendarID");
  // Get Spreadsheet Info
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName()
  Logger.log(name)
  var reden = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  var startDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue());
  var endDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue());
  startDate.setHours(0);
  startDate.setMinutes(00); 
  endDate.setHours(24);
  endDate.setMinutes(00);
  // Make calendar event
  var event = calendar.createEvent(
    (name.replace("Afwezigheids Formulier", "")+" "+reden), // here
    startDate,
    endDate
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should learn how to use regular expressions. You can learn about string class methods on a JavaScript reference site like Mozilla Developer Network (MDN). At the bottom of those method pages, be careful the function was not added in v5.1 / EMCAScript 2015 / etc, as Apps Script is older than that.

Comment: Alternatively, If you know the words, you can just replace it twice. `name.replace().replace()`

Comment: Thanks both for answering me, and I sure will have a look in learning this. Am going to try "the name.replace().replace()"and will reply back.

Comment: Just tried the answer of TheMaster, and he is his name worthy. Works perfectly. Learned something new :). Thanks again.  Am looking to mark his answer but so far no luck.